# Range of Times COUNTIF?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm wondering whether it's possible to have two columns of start and end times and be able to do some kind of count if to count available time slots?

Here is my test as an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fvCajUcmLMvTZLdKz20u5_GKGj1cYOmv1JrxAMP7VPg/edit?usp=drivesdk

I want to be able to count all the times between the written times as well as the times written. Hopefully that makes sense... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: The spreadsheet you shared can't be accessed. Please fix permissions.

Comment: Besides the point mentioned above, would you mind sharing your desired output as well? @MitchW

Comment: pls fix the gsheet link. + share some example of expected value for "some kind of count"